# Sharing OneLink.to URL to Facebook directs to Android only

Tags: android, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

On this very moment we are working on an application that has an embedded onelink link. It directs people from the game directly to Facebook through the Facebook SDK Sharelink function in Unity3d.
When we share this link on Facebook it only shows the Android link, while we want it to show the onelink as the crossplatform link it’s supposed to be.

We are using the **Unity3d** **FacebookSDK Plugin**.

For more information about Onelink go to: [OneLink](http://www.Onelink.to)

---

Thanks for your help in advance,

Menno

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both an iOS download URL and Android download URL for the fallback to be considered.

Comment: I'm not sure if you made a typo or what you mean. But the fallback URL is used when there is NO url for the other platforms (or the user is visiting from a platform that is not "supported"). Also, onelink.to doesn't seem to work correctly with Facebook as they caches the first link used. For it to change you need to rescrape it, which will trigger the fallback-url to be used once again and will in turn display on all other platforms.

Comment: What I mean is that the fallback URL will not be used unless you have both an iOS and an Android download URL.